# Templating not displaying after Craft server migration

Tags: craft2

A small team and I have inherited a Craft 2 site. We are brand new to craft with no previous experience with it. In wanting to work on offline copies of the sight the team is attempting to migrate the Craft site to our local LAMP servers.

The migration seems to have been somewhat successful. We are able to access the homepage of the site but there is no styling (please see image).

[image: image of HTML but no CSS styling]

In addition, the links click through to Not Found errors.

Not sure what additional information can be provided to help troubleshoot the problem. If I can provide the data I will! Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

ps. I wasn't sure if this is the correct place to ask this question. If it isn't please relocate it

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors in your browser's console?  Is the network tab in the console showing 404's?